# XMLHttpRequest: empty response

Tags: javascript

when I call

```
var zzz = new XMLHttpRequest();
zzz.open('GET', "http://freegeoip.net/json/", true);
zzz.send();
console.log(zzz);
```

In console log I can see `response` and `responseText`. But when I call

```
console.log(zzz.response);
```

I see response like `""`. What did i missed? How can I get json?

Comment: I think the server is overloaded, browser is waiting response for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The `true` in `zzz.open('GET', "http://freegeoip.net/json/", true);` means that the request is asynchronous. That means you need to wait for the request to finish.

```
var zzz = new XMLHttpRequest();
zzz.open('GET', "http://freegeoip.net/json/", true);
zzz.onload = function(){
    console.log(zzz.response);
    if (zzz.status === 200){
        // Probably good to make the you got a success code.
    }
};
zzz.onerror = function(err){
    // Handle the error
};
zzz.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `XMLHttpRequest` object completes its requests asynchronously when the third argument is set to `true`. That means the browser doesn't wait for an answer before continuing on. Right after you've called the `send()` function, the request hasn't completed yet and you're not going to be able to access the result.

The way JavaScript handles these is by telling the object what to do with a function. Ripping code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), what you want is something like this:

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "yourFile.txt", true);
oReq.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing the result, because not only is the request asynchronous by default - you're manually setting it to be asynchronous. Set the `async` flag (third argument to `.open()`) to `false` instead and you'll get the behavior you're expecting.

---

However, as @itdoesntwork points out below, using synchronous requests is a very bad practice. It's better to use asynchronous request and properly handle its result, as demonstrated in other answers.

Comment: True, but this locks up the browser and is generally not recommended

Comment: Yeah, sure. It's just the smallest change leading the poster to where he's trying to go. Whether he's heading into an abyss is another matter entirely :)